# Regular expression to match a comma not inside a string literal

Tags: java, regex, groovy, basic

In BASIC print statements can look like this:

```
100 PRINT "Copyright, Adrian McMenamin","maybe"
```

Which should put a tab space between the first statement and the second.

I am working on a DSL/interpreter for BASIC in Groovy/Java which needs to parse this line and produce something like:

```
print "Copyright, Adrian McMenamin", "    ","maybe"
```

(As Groovy interprets the comma as merely separating the parameters of the print function.)

So what regular expression will differentiate between the commas not inside the quote and those that are (don't worry about the PRINT or the line number etc)?

Comment: What is the grammar for strings in the BASIC language? Is it possible to have escaped quotation marks inside a string?

Comment: Why are you not tokenizing on commas and then join the resulting collection with tabs instead of trying to parse with regexes?

Comment: Yes, commas can appear inside string literals in BASIC. The tokenising point is a good one.

Comment: Since commas can appear in the strings, then, as Jack Maney points out in his comment to the answer below, you **cannot** use regular expressions. Regular expressions can **not** handle arbitrarily nested and escaped quotes (or parenthesis, or html tags, etc). No matter how much you *want* to use a regex to do this job, it simply can't handle it. You could write a mini-parser to run just when you need to handle a string

Comment: Mark, I mis read your comment - actually it's not possible to escape characters inside strings in this way in BASIC (or at least not in this, Sinclair, BASIC. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a very simple parser that just counted open quotes (modulo 2). It works given the simple rules for a BASIC string literal.
I had designed a very beautiful recursive function employing a regex that would work correctly for this form:

```
100 PRINT "Copyright, 2012", "Adrian McMenamin"
```

But which failed for this:

```
100 PRINT "Copyright, 2012"
```

Oh well, guess that's just the limit of a DFA-like scheme.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking at [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and [grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) which cannot be handled by regular expressions. Typically you would need to keep a count on open or closed brackets which is out of the scope of regular expressions. You might want to look at parsers like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) which solve this problem.
It might be *overkill* for just this task but I guess that you will have to translate multiple types of basic statement and then a parser is really what you need, not a regexp.

Comment: I know a regex cannot count, but it could recursively match on the untreated chunks. I am not using a parser because I don't know how and it does seem like overkill!

Comment: No, it is not overkill. `"For example, strings can have \"escaped quotes, and a lot more!\""`.

Comment: (Outside the scope of formal regular expressions, but not outside the scope of [all] "regular expression" implementations .. there are some *very scary* perl examples and I think a "recursive regular expression" could handle this, but that magic is beyond me. In any case, a general +1 answer.)